# How to implement many to many relationship in spring boot mongo db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have two Entities in my Spring-Boot mongoDb Application:

**Course.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Course {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      Long id;
      String title;
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      OptionCourse optionCourse;
      private double fee;
      @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "courses")
     private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

**Student.java**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      Long id;
      int age;
      String department;
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
     @JoinTable(name = "student_courses",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "course_id") })
   private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

for my mongoDb database:

I want to realise a **Many-to-Many-Relationship** between both Entities. Every courses should be able to assign multiple student.

How can i replace my annotations (@Entity, @Table,@Id, @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) and @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,...)) in my entities. I use spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb in my maven dependencies

Comment: mongo doesnt support relations, add "courseIds" property to student model and put course ids there. When you want to get course from student first you need to fetch "courseIds" then fetch course by given id(2 queries) otherwise you have to embed student into courses or courses into students but i dont recommend that.

Comment: hi @tknkrtl, can you show me this via the code to see how it looks please?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/many-to-many-relationship-and-linked-table-collection/130305